# SAPUI5 create HTML content in a view

Tags: sapui5

I am really new with SAPUI5 and I am just trying to make a web interface with 2 pages.

If you're familiar with angularjs, I would like to reproduce what we can do with the **ng-view** element.

So, how do I integrate the html code to my view?

Here is the code of my actual view:

```
    sap.ui.jsview("delaware_pimonitor.Dashboard", {


    getControllerName : function() {
        return "delaware_pimonitor.Dashboard";
    },


    createContent : function(oController) {
        var aControls = [];
           var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
             id : this.createId("MyButton2"),
             text : "Mubutton2"
           });
           aControls.push(oButton);


           return aControls;
    }

});
```

The examples on internet always show me how to create a button, but that's all...

Comment: So above code is not working

Comment: it is working but only for a button. And I don't understand how integrate html, for example where can I put the title of my page: <div class="pageTitle"><h1> Monitor </h1></div>

Comment: AS far as i know there is no there is no requirement of adding div in view.There are some controls such as label, field and whatever you want in sapui5. you can use that. But if you need div. You can add in on the startup page from where view are controlled, usually index.html

Comment: Assign class,id or name to that control and then then you can use normal javascript on it.

Comment: Hmm ok, I was thinking of this. But the HTML page is going to be so long...

Comment: You should have answered directly, I can't put your answer as good..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**ANSWER HERE**

Here is the answer: SHELL - https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/ux3/demokit/Shell.html

This allows you to create a panel and add pages or whatever you want inside it.
It is basically to make a top menu with each page of the website.

The demo in the last link, don't give all the code source.

**So here is the all code, which is actually working now:**
http://jsbin.com/duwoqova/1/edit

Thanks again

Comment: So you were asking to add more then one page or view(in sapui5). But in your above question you have written that you want to add html content such as div.So my answer was according to that only.

Comment: yes, i asked a precise question, but like you said it is not possible to add more pages in one view with the view. But you're right, I wanted to change the title of the discussion but i can't...

Comment: You can add. So you got the idea now. I was thinking that you were trying to add some html content in UI5

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XML views, then you can declare the `xhtml` namespace and use `html:*` tags inside your XML view definition. Like this:

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
  <Panel>
    <Button text="Press Me. I am a SAPUI5 Button"/>
    <html:button>No, press me. I am native HTML Button.</html:button>
  </Panel>
<mvc:View>
```

UI5 documentation: **[Using Native HTML in XML Views](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/be54950cae1041f59d4aa97a6bade2d8)**

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you don't use HTML code in sapui5(except for just making some div and appending some controls in it).Do all view related thing in your view. Make a layout in view and put all the controls under that layout and finalLy return it or append in div that you have created in index.html.As for example

```
sap.ui.jsview("delaware_pimonitor.Dashboard", {


getControllerName : function() {
    return "delaware_pimonitor.Dashboard";
},


    createContent : function(oController) {
        var aControls = [];
           var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
             id : this.createId("MyButton2"),
             text : "Mubutton2"
           });
           aControls.push(oButton);


           return aControls// or append to div using .placeAt("your div id");
    }
    });
```

Comment: Ok thanks, and if I want to give a behavior to a element in my index.html (instead of button here). 

    <a href="#" class="top-bar_nav_item"> Help </a>

how can I do this?

Comment: It is same as you were doing in html. Everything is same and you can control it it using javascript. Add javascript file in script src and control it behaviour from that js. Everything is similar to html and js